# adding ckeditor color button and font size

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, theming

I am new to drupal.
I am using drupal  8.2.5, bartik theme and i would like to add font size&family and colour buttons to the ckeditor.

i installed the "CKEditor Font Size and Family" module, enabled it and then at "admin-configuration-content authoring-text formats and editors" i configured "Basic HTML" and "Full HTML" and drag the new available buttons of fonts and size to the toolbar. I saved it and then when i tried to add new content (article or basic page), the editor was completely gone, there was only the field of "summary" available to write something!
When i disabled the module, the text editor was back to normal.

Later, I noticed at the module page that the installation process was the following:

1. Download the plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/font.
2. Place the plugin in the root libraries folder (/libraries).
3. Enable CKEditor Font in the Drupal admin.
4. Configure your WYSIWYG toolbar to include the buttons.

So I realised i hadn't followed step 2. I don't know where the libraries folder is, although i searched and have no experience how to create it correctly and how to place this plugin there. 
I read various posts on the internet but couldn't find a solution and then i ended up here. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the folder yourself as the docs say.

You can do this with command line with `mkdir libraries` in the webroot (where the /core folder is), or with a window and New Directory (New Folder) in either Windows / OSX.

Your application structure will then look like...

```
/core
/libraries
/modules
/themes
```

and so on.

All thats left is to download the JS plugin from ckeditor.com (v 4.5.x), unzip it, and place it in the libraries directory.

Comment: Hello, i created a libraries directory via cpanel in the webroot, where the /core folder is, i uploaded the plugin in the libraries, then activated the module but when i went to configure the toolbar, there was no available button for font or size to drag in the active area.Did i miss anything?Thank you once again.

Comment: You need to add the plugin.js and the icon and lang folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the console in your browser for any errors. In my case I hadn't added the panelbutton addon at the /libraries folder

Answer (score 0):

1. So you have created the Drupal/libraries folder. Ensure that you
   have downloaded and placed the library inside the library folder and
   the corresponding module in the Drupal/modules folder. (i had once
   copied module to library and viceversa). Try clearing the cache
   (Configuration->Performance->Cache) and run Configuration->Cron
   once.
2. You have mentioned that the editor is gone. This happens when there is a bug in the module. It happened with me for the 'color button' module. Search Configuration->reports to find the exact error. Once you get the error, you can search in this forum and I am sure a patch will be available for it.

Answer (score 0):

a.Download the plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/font.
b. enable that plugin.
c. Enable CKEditor Font in the Drupal admin.
d. Configure your WYSIWYG toolbar to include the buttons.